# google spreadsheet appscript permission error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a little problem with google spreadsheet.
i'm trying to get some json datas via ImportJSON function but what i want before getting data is clearing all contents of current sheet

```
function _get(func, id){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clearContents();
    url = "http://example.com";
    return ImportJSON(url);
}
```

when i call it in cell

```
=_get("place", "false")
```

it shows me an error

```
You do not have permission to call clearContents
```

am i missing something ?

Comment: Which version of GoogleSpreadsheet are you using, is it v3 or v4?

Comment: i'm using spreadsheet v4

Comment: In your case, unfortunately, the method of `clearContents()` cannot be used because of the specification of the custom function. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) Under this situation, when you want to use `clearContents()` in the custom function, how about this workaround? https://github.com/tanaikech/Enhanced-Custom-Function-for-Google-Spreadsheet-using-Web-Apps-as-Wrapper